# Question of Linear Resonse TDDFT

Tags: density-functional-theory

In the LR-TDDFT, from my unserstanding, it is based on the perturbation theory and there seems no time propagation involved, why it is called TDDFT?

Comment: This question would be more on topic in https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: 4 months is long for no answer. Please try on Materials.SE, which @CodyAldaz recommended